# Tree with cycle

Tags: java, binary-tree

So I wonder what would be the best approach to create structure from relation between employee-employer but with possible cycles for example

```
id: 1 boss: 2
id: 2 boss: 3
id: 3 boss: 1
Id: 4 boss: 1
id: 10 boss: 11
id: 11 boss: null
```

And then to be able then to find bosses of id 1 one for example

I ve been thinking about simple tree with reversed relation but how to prepare for cycles?

```
public class Tree<T> {
 private Node<T> root;

 public Tree(T rootData) {
    root = new Node<T>();
    root.data = rootData;
    root.employees = new ArrayList<Node<T>>();
 }

 public static class Node<T> {
    private T data;
    private List<Node<T>> employees ;
 }
}
```

Comment: Tree is acyclic by definition. What you need is probably a directed graph.

Comment: there will be disconnected components if you allow a cycle in an employee-employer relationship or you will need to allow multiple bosses for same employee.
What is your original usecase?

Comment: Ye so I ve bean thinking about list of trees. But still there will be problem with cycle

Comment: And each person can have few boses

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this problem with the design patterns.

I have used two patterns, so the pattern [composite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) and the patter [visitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)

I write the structure with this code

The interface for all node

```
public interface INode{
    //for appli visitor
    public void accept(IVisitor visitor);
}
```

For implementing your leaf node

```
public class INodeLeaf implements INode{

    public String getFoo();
}
```

For implementing your abstract class for the intermediary node, you can have more type of node intermediary

```
    public abstract class AbstractNode implements INode{

    private INode left;
    private INode right;

    public AbstractNode(INode left, INode right) {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }

    public INode getLeft() {
        return left;
    }

    public INode getRight() {
        return right;
    }

}
```

**You must have be at least a concrete node from AbstractNode**

For visit the structure you can implement the patter visitor, following this

```
public interface IVisitor {

    void visitNodeLeaf(NodeLeaf node);

    void visitYorConcreateNode(YourConcreateNode node);

}
```

an implementation can be

```
public class VisitorFoo implements IVisitor {

    private String foo;

    @Override
    public void visitNodeLeaf(INodeFoglia node) {
        foo += node.getFoo();
    }

    @Override
    public void visitYorConcreateNode(NodeDivisione node) {
        node.getLeft().accept(this);
        node.getRight().accept(this);
    }
}
```

**On the your question**

The my is general implementation of the Tree structure for the your example you can need the `List<INode>` an the method `visitYorConcreateNode(..)` inside the visitor should be visit the list but the implementation dosen't change.

**For operation complex on the structure**
For the complex operation on the strucutre I think it better use too the pattor [Strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

following this

```
public class StrategyFoo implement IStrategy{

   private IVisitor setTheVisitor;

//other
   public void runOperation(){//do nothind for moment}
}
```